# How to change view of InfoPath form in WorkFlow

Tags: workflow, infopath, task-list

Can you help me with my task: I'm creating a view/edit InfoPath form, using InfoPath Designer, for a task list where a workflow creates tasks.

In the workflow I change this:

```
createTask1_TaskProperties1.TaskType
```

How can I change the view of the InfoPath form from workflow code?

For example:

```
view1 if createTask1_TaskProperties1.TaskType = 1;
or
view2 if createTask1_TaskProperties1.TaskType = 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the view of Infopath form from a column/field in its formload event ...  Through workflow update the column using the action '**Update list item**'